# Create an ArrayList only containing Strings. Print using enhanced for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist

So here is my program:

Create an ArrayList that will only contain strings
Add the following to the list in order

- Mary
- John
- Mahendra
- Sara
- Jose
- Judy

Print the list using the enhanced for loop
Insert Harry in front of Mahendra and after John
Then Remove position 4 from the list

Here's what I've written:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        names.add(input.nextLine());
        names.add(input.nextLine());
        names.add(input.nextLine());
        names.add(input.nextLine());
        names.add(input.nextLine());
        names.add(input.nextLine());
        names.add(input.nextLine());

        for (String n : names) {
        System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I'm having problems with adding and removing. I believe everything else should be fine though.

Comment: Have you even looked at the javadoc for ArrayList ?

Comment: Nope but I've literally spent 4 hours everyday googling everything I can. I've tried a bunch of things within the development environment but didn't really get anywhere.

Comment: Then maybe it would be helpful to look at the javadoc.

Comment: How can you google for 4 hours and NOT end up at the javadocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use below methods to insert and remove:

```
void    add(int index, E element)
 E      remove(int index)
```

e.g. `Mahendra` is at index 2(index starts from 0), then to add `Harry` in front of `Mahendra`, just do as below:

```
  names.add(2, "Harry"); //This will push Mahendra at index 3
```

To remove crrent index 4,

```
  names.remove(4);
```

To remove previous index 4, which has become index 5 now,

```
  names.remove(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

indexOf() will let you find position of a given entry, add(index, object) will let you insert at an index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    names.add("Mary");
    names.add("John");
    names.add("Mahendra");
    names.add("Sara");
    names.add("Jose");
    names.add("Judy");

    names.add(names.indexOf("Mahendra"), "Harry");

    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```